# An interpolation problem

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, interpolation

> Let $f:[0,2]\to\Bbb{R}^+$ be the function give by $$f(x)=\sqrt{x(2-x)}.$$
>   I need to find (the exact values of) constants $a_1, a_2,a_3,a_4$ in $$g(x)=\sum_{k=1}^4a_kx^k(2-x)^k$$ such that $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in\{ \frac14,\frac12, \frac34, 1\}.$

Is there any easy way to do this using mathematica?

Also I would like to compare the graphs of $f$ and $g$.

Since I am not familiar with mathematica, can somebody help me to solve this. Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: Removing the endpoints helps but the equations are still linearly dependent because the equation $f(1/4)=g(1/4)$ is identical to the equation $f(7/4)=g(7/4)$ and so on.

Comment: @Nil Same technique works for your new domain of $k$. In fact it gives the same answer for the four `a[n]` variables as it should.

Comment: @Edmund: Thank you very much for your helpful detailed solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may use [`LinearSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearSolve.html) to solve for the `a[n]`.

Let

```
f[x_] := Sqrt[x (2 - x)]
g[x_] = Sum[a[k]*x^k*(2 - x)^k, {k, 0, 8}]
```

Note that I intentionally used [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) instead of [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) for `g`.

With

```
vars = a[#] & /@ Range[0, 8];
points = Range[0, 2, 1/4];
```

Then

```
m = CoefficientArrays[g[#], vars] & /@ points // Normal // #[[All, 2]] & ;
b = f /@ points ;
```

Call `LinearSolve`

```
ls = LinearSolve[m, b] // Simplify;
```

and construct `Rule`s of solution (`ls`) and variables (`vars`).

```
sol = MapThread[Rule, {vars, ls}];
sol // Column
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Check equality for `points` by `ReplaceAll` of `g` with `Rule`s in solution `sol`.

```
f[#] == g[#] /. sol & /@ points
```

> ```
> {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True}
> ```

Plot comparison.

```
Plot[{f[x], g[x] /. sol}, {x, 0, 2}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps

Comment: Interesting, I didn't realize `LinearSolve` doesn't give a warning when the system is underdetermined.

Comment: @Rahul Yes. It just comes out with the many zeros from the row reduction.

Comment: `vars = Array[a, 9, 0]`

Comment: @corey979 That is nice. (+1)  I don't use indexed variables that often so `Array` didn't come to mind.

Answer (score 7):

With the last update that reads:

> Let $f:[0,2]\to\Bbb{R}^+$ be the function give by $$f(x)=\sqrt{x(2-x)}.$$
>   I need to find (the exact values of) constants $a_1, a_2,a_3,a_4$ in $$g(x)=\sum_{k=1}^4a_kx^k(2-x)^k$$ such that $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in\{ \frac14,\frac12, \frac34, 1\}.$

---

Let's

```
f[x_] := Sqrt[x (2 - x)];
g[x_] := Sum[a[k] x^k (2 - x)^k, {k, 1, 4}];
vals = Range[1/4, 1, 1/4];
sol = Solve[g[#] == f[#] & /@ vals, Array[a, 4]][[1]];

Column @ sol
```

[image]

Matrix of the coefficients of the system of equations:

```
(m = Normal @
CoefficientArrays[g[#] == f[#] & /@ vals, 
  Array[a, 4]][[2]]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
MatrixRank @ m
```

> 4

so all equations are linearly independent.

```
g2[x_] = g[x] /. sol // Simplify
```

[image]

and

```
Plot[{f[x], g2[x]}, {x, 0, 2}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

---

**Alternatively**, one can actually *fit* a function to a dataset (below is a different case than previously):

```
Clear[f, g, vals]
f[x_] := Sqrt[x (2 - x)]
g[x_] := Sum[a[k] x^k (2 - x)^k, {k, 1, 8}]
args = Range[0, 2, 1/4];
vals = f /@ args;
data = Transpose @ {args, vals};

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, g[x], Array[a, 8], x];

nlm["ParameterTable"]
```

[image]

I skipped the `a[0]` to make the number of parameters smaller than the number of points to be fitted to.

```
g3[x_] = Normal @ nlm
```

[image]

```
Plot[{f[x], g3[x]}, {x, 0, 2}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Comparing the difference between `g2` and `g3`:

```
Plot[g2[x] - g3[x], {x, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

(Beware of the Runge's phenomenon [(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon)[(2)](http://math.boisestate.edu/~calhoun/teaching/matlab-tutorials/lab_11/html/lab_11.html)!)

Comment: Than you very much. I appreciate your continuous support to formulate the right question (+1).

Comment: Just to add a note: one can pretty much expect the Runge phenomenon to happen for sufficiently high degree if your interpolation points are not "clustered" near the endpoints.

Comment: Or simply `Solve@ Table[Sum[a[k] (x (2 - x))^k, {k, 4}] == f[x], {x, Range[4]/4}]`...